# Are there security concerns I should keep in mind when converting my app from Obj-C to Swift?

Tags: swift, security, exploit

I work on a large, old program owned by a large corporation. Soon, we hope to start moving from Objective-C to Swift. One of the reasons we want to move is because Swift is more secure than Objective-C. However, we'd love to avoid any security holes if possible. Aside from business logic, **are there any examples of safe code I might write in Obj-C that are inherently unsafe in Swift, or vice-versa?**

I'm mostly worried about user-provided data, and man-in-the-middle attacks spoofing as legitimate communications with our servers.

Comment: If this would better fit the topic of another site, please direct me there.

Comment: Why do you say it's more secure? It's safer, but that's a completely separate issue. It's not appreciably more secure, IMHO. The security concerns are largely the same as the Objective-C concerns.

Comment: @Rob because it appears to be designed to make it harder to leave in security holes like buffer overflows. To what concerns are you referring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I think the move to Swift is prudent, but I think it overstates the case to argue that Swift is significantly more secure that Objective-C. Even, in Objective-C, if you avoid C-like manipulation of buffers and stick with Cocoa classes, you're generally safe from buffer overruns and the like.

But if this is your concern, my main Swift caveats would be to carefully review any use of the appropriately named "unsafe buffer pointers" (e.g. `unsafeAddressOf`, `unsafeBufferPointer`, `UnsafeMutablePointer`, etc.). Also, review any C API that you have to call that still takes buffer pointers.

My earlier point was merely that this is such a small portion of the overall security risks, that I'm not sure this would be very high in my list of Swift transition rationale. Swift, itself, does little to address more egregious concerns such as failure to sandbox and use keychain, sloppy network and/or cache management, etc., as discussed in WWDC 2015 [Security and Your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-706/) and WWDC security presentations from prior years. These sorts of security concerns are addressed through a rigorous development process including judicious design, coding, testing, and reviews, but can be tackled equally effectively in both Objective-C and Swift.